# how to avoid multiple logins with weblogic

Tags: jsf, authentication, weblogic, oracle-adf

I want to avoid multiple logins with the same principal or user across different browsers or computers, I developed my webapp using ADF/JSF and deplyed on weblogic 10.3. Could you help me?

Comment: What do you need to know? How to check if someone is logged in more than once? How to reject a log in by the same person from more than one place?

Comment: Yes, exactly that is what I want. Could you help me?

Comment: You will have to provide a lot more information before someone can help you. What security environment are you using? Picket? Apache Shiro? What credential repository are you using?

Comment: I'm using Oracle Portable security service (OPSS) that supported in weblogic server.